# Is there a way to generate a kernel core dump file after a kernel panic occurred on OSX?

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, kernel

I need to debug a kernel panic and the current information in the kernel panic log file is insufficient.

The only information available on that matter is in the following link:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html

but it talks about creating a server for core dump and it must be done locally (user's computer). Both Windows and Linux support local dump file.

So, is there a way to generate a kernel core dump file after a kernel panic occurred on OSX?

Comment: Using dtrace is the simplest avenue, but the article you linked to lists several ways to generate kernel dumps. sudo dtrace -w -n "BEGIN{ panic();}" Happy debugging

Comment: I need a way to generate a kernel core dump file, not the kernel panic. For this I have many ways, planned or not :)

Comment: What do you expect to be in the dump file if no actual panic gets triggered? (Assuming it is a file you can debug. You'll probably want to edit your question to explain what precisely you are looking to do.)

Comment: Changed both title and the question.

Comment: @thanks before I change this answer to be basically, no, you say the panic log file is insufficient - is it truncated or are the registers and stack mostly empty?

Comment: Most operating system allow you to dump the entire memory space of the kernel. OSX only provides you a way to dump it into a server instead of a local file (I understand their motive to protect the HD). 

I thought perhaps someone might have a solution for this, but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Dumping past kernel details after the fact would be like magic. Are you conflating remote debugging of a running kernel with the panic.log file that gets stored to disk perhaps?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

Windows has the ability to dump the _entire_ kernel memory to a file. And it's an ability I need in order to debug an abnormality in my code. 

OSX supports such behaviour (dumping kernel memory) by using a remote server. I thought perhaps it will be possible to dump it to a file in the paniced machine. However, looking through the kernel panic source code in xnu, it is not possible.

Comment: @mrdvlpr: This answer gets cut off, it would be great if you could answer your own question with this comment and mark it answered!

Comment: The link in the answer provide a solution (not great, though...) I did not find another way around. Firewire kernel debugging was my best solution.